# Openstack VM build fails with error

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I have installed OpenStack Victoria according to the official guide https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/index.html

But if I now start a VM into the public network it fails with an error.

The log from /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log gives hints for a problem with network interface allocation. As this hints for a problem with Neutron this is the log from /var/log/neutron/linuxbridge-agent.log

```
2020-12-05 14:03:29.853 64594 INFO oslo_rootwrap.client [-] Spawned new rootwrap daemon process with pid=64641
2020-12-05 14:03:29.898 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.linuxbridge.agent.linuxbridge_neutron_agent [-] Agent initialized successfully, now running... 
2020-12-05 14:03:29.984 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] RPC agent_id: lb0800273e5409
2020-12-05 14:03:29.996 64594 INFO neutron.agent.agent_extensions_manager [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Loaded agent extensions: []
2020-12-05 14:03:30.369 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Linux bridge agent Agent RPC Daemon Started!
2020-12-05 14:03:30.370 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Linux bridge agent Agent out of sync with plugin!
2020-12-05 14:03:30.378 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.linuxbridge.agent.arp_protect [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Clearing orphaned ARP spoofing entries for devices []
2020-12-05 14:03:30.384 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.linuxbridge.agent.arp_protect [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Clearing orphaned ARP spoofing entries for devices []
2020-12-05 14:03:52.775 64594 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-73a64891-7e31-4eb3-a239-95ed0fe2778e bf0a9cf61e274913a7aa008456983ac7 765fd6ec621541e79a25025e369b5d8e - - -] Security group rule updated ['1930fac4-ce50-43c5-9d3c-27f74f0cf7d3']
2020-12-05 14:03:55.461 64594 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-05ed49a3-cd0b-4c77-a373-49e11f87c5d4 bf0a9cf61e274913a7aa008456983ac7 765fd6ec621541e79a25025e369b5d8e - - -] Security group rule updated ['1930fac4-ce50-43c5-9d3c-27f74f0cf7d3']
2020-12-05 14:04:03.603 64594 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-2074a6e2-c3f0-4571-9e01-512ca82a55c0 cdf0bd9915bd4cada14ae2c6d3a96fc3 7d5fcbecde094b10ad0a682635624715 - - -] Security group rule updated ['9e8e7e40-ef0b-4933-911a-191f6d4dd6cc']
2020-12-05 14:04:06.321 64594 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-f1927b97-50fd-4b27-a9ad-817d9b05ba6f cdf0bd9915bd4cada14ae2c6d3a96fc3 7d5fcbecde094b10ad0a682635624715 - - -] Security group rule updated ['9e8e7e40-ef0b-4933-911a-191f6d4dd6cc']
2020-12-05 14:13:30.922 64594 INFO oslo_rootwrap.client [-] Rootwrap daemon process exit with status: 0
2020-12-05 14:17:57.318 64594 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-9ec444c1-bdb4-4a92-b55b-42318b177db0 cdf0bd9915bd4cada14ae2c6d3a96fc3 7d5fcbecde094b10ad0a682635624715 - - -] Security group member updated ['9e8e7e40-ef0b-4933-911a-191f6d4dd6cc']
2020-12-05 14:18:02.291 64594 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Preparing filters for devices {'tap4ce7383f-15'}
2020-12-05 14:18:02.440 64594 WARNING oslo_rootwrap.client [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Leaving behind already spawned process with pid 64641, root should kill it if it's still there (I can't)
2020-12-05 14:18:02.632 64594 INFO oslo_rootwrap.client [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Spawned new rootwrap daemon process with pid=64808
2020-12-05 14:18:02.933 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Port tap4ce7383f-15 updated. Details: {'device': 'tap4ce7383f-15', 'network_id': 'd367dc02-c456-428e-b332-bf3bcd04c96b', 'port_id': '4ce7383f-15d3-4b9f-87f6-93a221352dd1', 'mac_address': 'fa:16:3e:22:87:81', 'admin_state_up': True, 'network_type': 'flat', 'segmentation_id': None, 'physical_network': 'provider', 'mtu': 1500, 'fixed_ips': [{'subnet_id': '22bd48b3-b747-4afe-a5e3-661745130284', 'ip_address': '172.17.4.156'}], 'device_owner': 'compute:nova', 'allowed_address_pairs': [], 'port_security_enabled': True, 'qos_policy_id': None, 'network_qos_policy_id': None, 'profile': {}, 'propagate_uplink_status': False}
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Error in agent loop. Devices info: {'current': {'tap4ce7383f-15'}, 'timestamps': {'tap4ce7383f-15': 6}, 'added': {'tap4ce7383f-15'}, 'removed': set(), 'updated': set()}: pyroute2.netlink.exceptions.NetlinkError: (13, 'Permission denied')
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/agent/_common_agent.py", line 465, in daemon_loop
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     sync = self.process_network_devices(device_info)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 160, in wrapper
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     result = f(*args, **kwargs)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/agent/_common_agent.py", line 214, in process_network_devices
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     resync_a = self.treat_devices_added_updated(devices_added_updated)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 160, in wrapper
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     result = f(*args, **kwargs)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/agent/_common_agent.py", line 231, in treat_devices_added_updated
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     self._process_device_if_exists(device_details)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/agent/_common_agent.py", line 258, in _process_device_if_exists
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     device, device_details['device_owner'])
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 585, in plug_interface
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     network_segment.mtu)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 521, in add_tap_interface
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     return False
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     self.force_reraise()
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     raise value
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 513, in add_tap_interface
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     tap_device_name, device_owner, mtu)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 546, in _add_tap_interface
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     mtu):
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 497, in ensure_physical_in_bridge
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     physical_interface)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 285, in ensure_flat_bridge
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     if self.ensure_bridge(bridge_name, physical_interface):
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 455, in ensure_bridge
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     self.update_interface_ip_details(bridge_name, interface)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 417, in update_interface_ip_details
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     gateway)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 393, in _update_interface_ip_details
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     dst_device.addr.add(cidr=ip['cidr'])
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/ip_lib.py", line 528, in add
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     add_broadcast)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/linux/ip_lib.py", line 802, in add_ip_address
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     device, namespace, scope, broadcast)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_privsep/priv_context.py", line 247, in _wrap
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     return self.channel.remote_call(name, args, kwargs)
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_privsep/daemon.py", line 224, in remote_call
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     raise exc_type(*result[2])
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent pyroute2.netlink.exceptions.NetlinkError: (13, 'Permission denied')
2020-12-05 14:18:03.075 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent 
2020-12-05 14:18:04.307 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Linux bridge agent Agent out of sync with plugin!
2020-12-05 14:18:04.309 64594 INFO neutron.agent.securitygroups_rpc [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Preparing filters for devices {'tap4ce7383f-15'}
2020-12-05 14:18:04.574 64594 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Port tap4ce7383f-15 updated. Details: {'device': 'tap4ce7383f-15', 'network_id': 'd367dc02-c456-428e-b332-bf3bcd04c96b', 'port_id': '4ce7383f-15d3-4b9f-87f6-93a221352dd1', 'mac_address': 'fa:16:3e:22:87:81', 'admin_state_up': True, 'network_type': 'flat', 'segmentation_id': None, 'physical_network': 'provider', 'mtu': 1500, 'fixed_ips': [{'subnet_id': '22bd48b3-b747-4afe-a5e3-661745130284', 'ip_address': '172.17.4.156'}], 'device_owner': 'compute:nova', 'allowed_address_pairs': [], 'port_security_enabled': True, 'qos_policy_id': None, 'network_qos_policy_id': None, 'profile': {}, 'propagate_uplink_status': False}
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [req-56f4d58e-282f-40de-8930-fe8f9e83c817 - - - - -] Error in agent loop. Devices info: {'current': {'tap4ce7383f-15'}, 'timestamps': {'tap4ce7383f-15': 6}, 'added': {'tap4ce7383f-15'}, 'removed': set(), 'updated': set()}: pyroute2.netlink.exceptions.NetlinkError: (13, 'Permission denied')
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/agent/_common_agent.py", line 465, in daemon_loop
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     sync = self.process_network_devices(device_info)
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 160, in wrapper
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     result = f(*args, **kwargs)
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/agent/_common_agent.py", line 214, in process_network_devices
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     resync_a = self.treat_devices_added_updated(devices_added_updated)
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osprofiler/profiler.py", line 160, in wrapper
2020-12-05 14:18:04.692 64594 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     result = f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong there. If additional information is required just tell me what to supply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. After days and reading billions of Google search results, I found the solution:

**Disabling IPv6**

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and load it with `sysctl -p` afterwards:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And no, I do *not* know why IPv6 made this fail...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points for writing comments (hint! hint!), so I am writing an answer, although this may not be a solution to your problem.

There is a single English-language web page that reports both "*error in agent loop*" and "*permission denied*". The problem was resolved by reinstalling Neutron: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/121433/openstack-rocky-vm-not-spawning-on-provider-network-though-it-is-successfully-getting-spawned-on-self-service-network.